# Who wrote the code? Svn code tracking system

Tags: svn, version-control

I recently came across a piece of code, that I thought was very funny. Apart from being funny, I needed to find out who checked in that piece of code, to maintain code quality in our application.

Is there a mechanism to dig in the owner of the code from svn? So If I highlight a piece of code, I can get information on when it was checked in and who committed it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should try out [`blame`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re02.html):

```
svn blame <file>
```

Comment: You're welcome! If you'd like, you could use a system like Trac to parse that output and visually display each line's origin in different colors (it's just easier to scan :))

Answer (score 4):

May be you are looking for [svn blame](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re02.html)

From description:
"Show author and revision information in-line for the specified files or URLs"

Also works in git and mercurial.

Answer (score 0):

you can see the history of who checked in that file. How many distinct committers on that file are there? Do you also need to know the exact revision in which the funny code was committed?

Answer (score 0):

Or you could also try this : svn log | head -n, where n is the last n commits you want to see. I am sure this would help.